# How can i change the legend icon color according to my SfCartesianChart?

Tags: flutter, syncfusion

**want to change the legend icon color according to my SfCartesianChart ?**

```
LineSeries<SalesData, DateTime>(
                    
                    name: "Kw",
                    dataSource: graphData("value2"),
                    xValueMapper: (SalesData sales, _) => sales.year,
                    yValueMapper: (SalesData sales, _) => sales.sales,
                    pointColorMapper: (SalesData sales, _) => Colors.amberAccent),
```

The color i have specified for my line chart is Colors.amberAccent . But my legends icon  colors showing default
**SfCartesianChart**  colors. it is not changing according to my line charts line color.

**The library i am using is syncfusion**

Answer (score 1):

We have analyzed the customer’s scenario with provided information and we would like to share some information regarding the Legend rendering behaviour available in the chart. On checking the provided code snippet, we found that you have used the **pointColorMapper** property to set the color for the line series and as the point color mapper feature available in the chart is only used to provide different colors for different segments of the series, we have rendered the series legend color using default chart color. In this case, if you want to change the color of the legend you can use the **onLegendItemRender** callback event available in the chart to change the color of the series legend as required using its arguments.

```
SfCartesianChart(
        // Event to customize the legend on rendering
        onLegendItemRender: (args) {
          // Setting color for the series legend based on its index.
          if (args.seriesIndex == 0) {
            args.color = Colors.amberAccent;
          }
        },
        primaryXAxis: DateTimeAxis(),
        // Enable legend
        legend: Legend(isVisible: true),
        series: <ChartSeries<_SalesData, DateTime>>[
          LineSeries<_SalesData, DateTime>(
              dataSource: chartData,
              xValueMapper: (_SalesData sales, _) => sales.year,
              yValueMapper: (_SalesData sales, _) => sales.sales,
              pointColorMapper: (_SalesData sales, _) => Colors.amberAccent)
        ]
      )
    )
```

The sample for reference can be found below.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cfakw5vGqoYGXfdCnT101_DgetDGHxNN/view?usp=sharing

Note: for cartesian charts a legend will rendered for the whole series and not for each data points in the series.

For further reference on the **onlegendItemRender** event and the **pointColorMapper** property, please check the following links.

- onLegentItemRender - https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/callbacks#onlegenditemrender
- pointColorMapper - https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/series-customization#color-mapping-for-data-points

Also to mention that if you want to set single color for the whole series then, you can use the [**color**](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/CartesianSeries/color.html) property of the cartesian chart series and in this case the legend icon will automatically renders in the respective series color only.

Comment: i have used color property for every single set of linechart. and it worked fine. thanks for the reply TEAM syncfusion.